# matrix result needed to show consistency of equation

Tags: linear, blue

I am trying to show the following system of equation

Va+Xb=0 and
X'a=k,

is consistent when a'X=k', where V is nXn and X is nXp (p<n) matrix, a,b,k are vectors.
I could not find the reason how Va belong to column space of X.
The above equation is the consequence of minimizing variance of linear estimator of linear parametric function, using Lagrange Multiplier..

Comment: Using math typesetting will make this question easier to read, and more likely to get answers. More information: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Although it's unclear what are the fixed quantities and what are the variables, making it difficult to interpret this question, bear in mind that the column space of $X$ is the set of all $X\beta$ as $\beta$ ranges through $\mathbb{R}^p.$  Because the first equation is equivalent to $Va=X(-b),$ *a fortiori* $Va$ is in this column space.

Comment: Column space of X is spanned by Xβ , where β is in p- dimensional Eucledian space over real line. My question is how to ascertain that Va belong to column space of X, where vector a satisfies a'X=k'. I think the result is true from the framework of minimization itself.